# Calling base component's methods/features

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, module, vue-component

Having `Base.vue`

```
<template><div>{{ name }}</div></template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {name: 'Example Component'};
    }
  };
</script>
```

And `Extended.vue`:

```
<script>
  import Base from './Base.vue';
  export default {
    extends: Base,
    data() {
      return {name: 'Extended Example Component'};
    }
  };
</script>
```

Is it possible to reuse `data` from base one instead of hardcoding `Extended Example Component`? Some kind of `super` from OOP? Looking for generic solution involving stuff like `mount`, `methods`, `computed`, etc.

**UPDATE**

When using OOP we use such approach (Python example):

```
class Base:
   def __init__(self):
       self.name = 'Example Component'


class Extended(Base):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.name = f'Extended {self.name}'
```

This way we reuse `self.name` field.

Comment: Please, clarify what are your expectations. *instead of hardcoding Extended Example Component* - but it was hardcoded because it should differ from Base, wasn't it? `extends` and `mixins` merge data and other options, that's their purpose

Comment: @EstusFlask so you mean that extends is not the best option in this use case? So maybe any alternative approach suggestion?

Comment: If you do not override "name" in the child, then accessing "name" will get the parent value, ie "Example Component", which is what we expect. So I don't see what you're asking for.

Comment: @jaudo That's an exact question: how to refer to `name` value of `Base` component inside `Extended` component? Mind that `name` is a field of `data`, so I am asking more generically about `data`. I am also interested in other features such as `mounted`, `computed`, `methods`, etc.

Comment: Using this.name will access to Base value. Except if it is overriden in Extended. In this case, base value is not reachable (as in all OOP langagues I know)

Comment: I mean that `extends` is the best option as it already extends data, computed, etc in a determined way, but it's not intended to be used the way you expect. For what you're trying to do with `name`, it's better to provide custom static data in component options and access it as `$options` (btw it collides with Vue's own `name` option). This can be seen in Vue plugins. I'll try to post an answer later.

Comment: @EstusFlask I see. That would be probably an answer for asked question and will be appreciated with up vote at least. But actually that still doesn't solve my issue. I didn't underline that in my question because I didn't think it might go that way, but I am actually trying to override external component with my custom functionality, so placing `name` as option will not help me. Assumption in my case is that I can't change `Base` component.

Answer (score 1):

`extends` and `mixins` merge options [in a specified way](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html#option-merging), this is the official way to inherit component functionality. They don't provide full control over the inheritance.

For static data that may change between component definitions (`Base` and `Extended`) custom options are commonly used:

```
export default {
  myName: 'Component',
  data() {
    return { name: this.$options.myName };
  }
}
```

and

```
export default {
  extends: Base,
  myName: `Extended ${Base.options.myName}`
}
```

Notice that `name` is [existing Vue option](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#name) and shouldn't be used for arbitrary values.

Any reusable functions can be extracted from component definition to separate exports.

For existing components that cannot be modified `data` and other base component properties can be accessed where possible:

```
  data() {
    let name;

    name = this.$data.name;
    // or
    name = Base.options.data.call(this).name;

    return { name: `Extended ${name}` };
  }
```

This approach is not future-proof and not compatible with composition API, as there's no clear distinction between `data`, etc, and `this` is unavailable in setup function. An instance can be accessed with `getCurrentInstance` but it's internal API and can change without notice.

Answer (score 0):

The data object is a kind of state for a single component, hence the data object inside a component can only be accessed in that component and not from outside or other components.

For your specific requirement, you can use Vuex. It helps you access the state in multiple components. Simply define a state in the vuex store and then access the state in the component.

If you don't want to use Vuex, then another simple solution is to store the data in localStorage and then access the data in multiple components.

Comment: Keeping data in local storage unfortunately is not an option because in my real-life scenario I am trying to override external component.

Answer (score -1):

You can access your data, from child component. You can do that by this.$parent.nameOfTheDataYouHave.
This [cheatsheet](https://www.vuemastery.com/pdf/Vue-Essentials-Cheat-Sheet.pdf) can help you with the basics of the component anatomy and lifecycle hooks(mounted,created,etc..).
And last [this](https://jithilmt.medium.com/vue-js-2-two-way-data-binding-in-parent-and-child-components-1cd271c501ba) is the proper way of two-way binding data (parent-child).

Comment: `$parent` refers to the parent component, not base one. That's not a nesting issue, it's about component inheritance.

Comment: Sorry, i meant child component.I edited original.
If i got it correctly, mixins do what you want. You can create a mixin with full or partial component anatomy and use it in whatever component you want as it extends the mixin you import.